# My android smartphone showing strange behaviour

Tags: android, smartphone

Recently I am experiencing very strange behavior on my android smartphone such as:

- apps minimising/maximising unexpectedly
- suddenly it taps on other parts of the screen that I am not touching
- while browsing the web it scrolls or taps on a link on the webpage
- sometimes while chatting types letters on its own.

They happen while I am using the phone. Sometimes those symptoms happen a couple of times a day and sometimes every few days.

Could it be malware?

Comment: Sure it could be. It could also be a faulty screen. A loose wire or connection would make it intermittent based on how you held it or if there was pressure on the case.

Comment: If all of this happens while you are also interacting with the touchscreen itself, I’d also consider whether the touchscreen might be defective.

Comment: "Could strange behaviour in X be attributed to malware?" The answer is categorically "yes". I'm not sure what you really meant to ask.

Comment: Mostly it happens when i am holding the cellphone and the screen is unlocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not necessarily this happens in my phone too when charging and just disappear when I lock the screen and unlock it again .

Well if you are not okay with consider scanning it with some antivirus and malware protection app.

Better u report to manufacturer or have a visit to service center.

I hope that will help.